# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1

Tags: android, gradle

So, I'm running into an odd issue. I want to upgrade my gradle from version `2.14.1` to `5.5.1` and it won't let me.

Here's the error I get:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1.
            Searched in the following locations:
            - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.pom
            - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.jar
            Required by:
            project :
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 664 ms)
```

I was looking through some older posts and they all detail what it was required by and project but oddly, it's blank above.

Here's how my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I also double checked the gradle path in `Android Studio > Properties > Gradle > Use local Gradle distribution` and I have it set to the root `gradle-5.5.1` directory.

The log isn't helpful either, it says the same thing as above:

```
2019-07-14 08:28:28,670 [thread 268]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.5.1/gradle-5.5.1.jar
Required by:
    project :

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (5 s 536 ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: `App > build.gradle:`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'


    signingConfigs {
        liveConfig
                {
                   //removed due to privacy 
                }

        devConfig
                {
                 //removed due to privacy
                }

    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.liveConfig
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_SERVICES_LIVE", "true"
            //no app created for flurry live tagging
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_FLURRY_LIVE", "true"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_FLURRY_QA", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://media.company.com/WebServices/prod/mobileapps/cc/data/\""

        }

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.devConfig
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_SERVICES_LIVE", "true"
            //no app created for flurry live tagging
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_FLURRY_LIVE", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_FLURRY_QA", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://media.company.com/WebServices/prod/mobileapps/cc/data/\""

        }

    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    dataBinding{
        enabled true;
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation files('libs/android-binding-v0.6-preview.jar')
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:8.2.0@aar'
    implementation files('libs/ormlite-android-5.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ormlite-core-5.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'

    def appCenterSdkVersion = '2.0.0'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This dependency corresponds to the **Android** gradle plugin, not Gradle itself. Typically, the Android gradle plugin should match the version number of your Android Studio installation (e.g. "3.4.2").

If you want to update Gradle itself, and you are using the gradle wrapper, update the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file and edit the `distributionUrl` line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5.1-all.zip
```

If you are using a local distribution, then you don't have to do anything. Your project will be built using the gradle distribution set in the Android Studio settings (in your case, Gradle 5.5.1).

Edit: It seems that your build.gradle file is also missing the `google()` repositories, here is what it should look like if you want to use the Android gradle plugin 3.4.2:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm running Android Studio 3.4.2 right now and I still get the error. Are you saying I need Gradle version 3.4.2 instead?

Comment: You need the Android gradle plugin version 3.4.2 (not the same as gradle 3.4.2). Gradle is the build system, the Android gradle plugin just tells gradle how to build android apps. You can update gradle independently of the plugin. In your case, you have apparently already set Gradle to version 5.5.1 in the Android Studio settings, so you have nothing else to do.

Comment: How do I get the android gradle plugin 3.4.2? Clearly, something is not working. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your build.gradle file, use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`. And in the Android Studio settings, point to Gradle 5.5.1 (as you have already done). Then it should be working.

Comment: ok I did that but I'm now getting: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
haha. EDIT: Actually, embedding maven repository option came up and I clicked on that.That seemed to resolve the gradle issue above but now I'm getting dependency issues @_@.

Comment: Well it seems that your gradle file is missing the `google()` repositories, I have edited my answer with a working example.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work but now I have one more issue lol: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:31:5-226:19 to override.

Comment: That is, I try to add that to the manifest file but I get this error: "The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an element type "application" is not bound."

Comment: I'm glad that it worked! However that looks like a completely different issue, I think that you should ask it as a different question.

Comment: My guess would be that you are missing the lines `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in the gradle.properties file.

Comment: I see that duplicate class names were found, one in the old support libraries and one in the new AndroidX libraries. Can you please add your `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException added gradle to edited post. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I see you are trying to use the old support libraries (take a look at your dependencies) assuming you added the two lines Dalmas suggested then you should use the AndroidX packages instead. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migratewill tell you the correct way to migrate and the dependencies you need to switch out.

Comment: I'm sorry, the website is actually https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException Is it required to migrate to Android X if I want to target api 28? Thanks!

Comment: @Euridice01 No, but it is recommended.

Comment: Ok I started to migrate everything over for support libraries but I can't find an equivalent for this: 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Comment: My google() repositories were missing. This solved my problem

Comment: "the version number of your Android Studio installation" - where can I find this? On MacOS it appears to be a dated version with 2020 in it 

Answer (score 3):

From [mavnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google) Google tab, latest stable version:

```
implementation group: 'com.android.tools.build', name: 'gradle', version: '3.4.2'
```

Latest alpha:

```
implementation group: 'com.android.tools.build', name: 'gradle', version: '3.6.0-alpha04'
```

**Note**: Only use the Android Gradle Plugin that matches your AS version. For example, you are using AS 3.4.2, so use the Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.2

Comment: Nooo. If the OP is running AS 3.4.2 then changing the Android Gradle Plugin to `3.6.0-alpha04` is **not the way to go**. AS 3.4.2 will throw an error stating that it cannot build the project because it cannot run an Android Gradle Plugin with a newer version number. It will force you to change the Android Gradle plugin version or use AS 3.6

Comment: I never said he should

Comment: I am suggesting that you should delete that part.

Comment: He should know what his options are, and that was a bad comment

Comment: Then at least add a note saying not to use `3.6.0-alpha04` unless you are running AS Canary 3.6, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue with gradle 7.0.2

Adding `google()` under `jcenter()` in `build.gradle` file worked for me

Something like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Android Studio menu, Preferences > Build Execution and Deployment > Build > Gradle
and select "'gradle.wrapper.properties' file" in the "Use Gradle From:" menu.

Select your gradle version and plugin version from here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

Set the gradle version in the top build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
}
```

Set the plugin version in the gradle.wrapper.properties file, for example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

Sync Gradle and Build.