# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1

Tags: java, android, gradle

In a fresh AS project we have error. in our proxy settings we have error too. see the screenshot below:

[image: Android Studio settings]

How can we solve error?

UPDATE:

When we use auto detect, after click to try sync, below window opened:

[image: check poiner area]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027443/gradle-sync-failed-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle5-5-1)

Comment: thank you but i don't know what is the best versions shoud i use . 4.0.1 ? 4.0.1 ? 4.1.0 ? or ...?

Comment: This is always the same version as Android Studio has. The screenshot clearly tells that it doesn't like the proxy's host-name, which seems to be correct & is accessible (from Europe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try use IP address (of `fodev.org`? are you sure this is correct?) in this case see whether it works?

You can tick the `auto-detect proxy settings` see whether it helps or not.

Comment: I don't know what i have to fill in URL in auto mode. or in manual mode fields.

Comment: "auto-detect" obviously only works within a LAN, but not the internet.

Comment: please check post update

Comment: I thought @AminShabanzadeh are in a company network? Not sure why AS doesn't allow short proxy domain, you just use IP address try first. Forget the auto-detect, if that screen popup, mean it is not able to auto-detect.

Comment: note: i live in iran, ASIATECH ISP & wifi lan.  i use 2 vpn: 1- ProtonVPN 2-20speed.co

Comment: Are you restricted to use VPN and proxy? If not, turn them off and make a gradle build, see whether the issue are whether caused by them.

Comment: that's it! really thank you.it works with protonVPN.

Comment: lol... which step make it works?

Answer (score 0):

[`fodev.org:8118`](http://fodev.org:8118) seems to be accessible, at least from here. Maybe try to use another proxy, or find a VPN provider, that offers endpoints in your country of residence. As a paying customer you could bug them, when it doesn't work - not so with some free of charge service alike: https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod