# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.1

Tags: java, android, gradle

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.1.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

so, guys my android studio is been showing this after I import any project [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.1.] please help trying

I am unable to do something to solve the error because technically I didn't get the error that is why I need your help drop some solutions

Comment: Does this happen after importing a specific project, or everything?

Comment: I don't understand: if you *technically* didn't get the error, how did you get it?

Comment: you need to download ```gradle:6.7.1``` or change the version lookout this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57027520/12709358

Answer (score 8):

**gradle plugin version** 6.7.1 does not exist. go to `build.gradle(project)` and change it to latest version 4.2.0 .

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'

  
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }


     }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and **Gradle version** 6.7.1 must be in `gradle-wrapper.properties` :

```
#Fri Jun 11 14:09:32 IRDT 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```